# How to incorporate WordPress blog into a static website?

Tags: wordpress, architecture, blog

I'm a designer and front-end web designer and I have a client that wants me to put her wordpress into a static site. Is there a way that I can embed the blog into a new site? Or is there a way that I can create a back door so that even though she cannot read html she can add new updates to the site?

I've been looking for the answer, but can't seem to figure it out. Please let me know what my options are.

Comment: What does "put her wordpress into a static site" mean exactly? Do you want the static pages to become editable in Wordpress?

Comment: Hmm, I voted to close on the basis of the (original) title and a skim of the question.  Now, I'm feeling that there is the basis of a valid question here, and I hope @lauren follows up with soem more info so we can deliver a helpful answer.

Comment: This should go to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are so many Wordpress questions that need to be over there.

Answer (score 3):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways you can do it. "Reverse engineer" the database and use MySQL in PHP code to get the news articles, though it's pretty trivial, and use a few filter functions defined in the WP headers to transform the post content.

Or use the functions entirely from the WP headers, described in http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website.

I did this with my band's website and use Disqus comments to add comments to my static site, but didn't think of using the functions method and went for... manual approach. Either way, it's basically just getting the post data yourself and spewing it out using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a method of displaying blog content on a static site. You could do this several ways. One way would be to use an Iframe, another would be to use a module that allows you to display contents of an RSS feed.

Here is info about the iframe tag if you are unfamiliar with it.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

For displaying an RSS feed try looking for an open source module like:
http://www.zazar.net/developers/zrssfeed/

http://www.rssreader.magix-cjquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old but Google is still showing it.

In 2023, Jamstack is a big thing, people are using Wordpress for its REST API and using services such as Netlify to host the front-end, based on React or whatever Javascript framework you want. [See the Netlify with Wordpress page](https://www.netlify.com/with/wordpress/).

This is typically referred to as "headless CMS."

The marketing folks still get the familiar Wordpress backend to make updates. I just use Netlify as an example, there are dozens of Jamstack/headless CMS hosts, I imagine. Not making any recommendations, it's the only one I have experience with.

Using one of these services like Netlify, as opposed to a traditional (for example GoDaddy or Bluehost) Wordpress installation, leaves you lacking email and other services that traditional hosts package in their hosting plans.

So you have to consider if your customer has the technical savvy to maintain such a complex setup. You could just stick with Wordpress and get static pages. There are great Wordpress sites that make static pages, such as WP Rocket (and Rocket CDN).